# Switching voltage regulator

Tags: switching-regulator

I have a few circuits here that work with 42v to 5v/3.3v regulation. To achieve that there is a switching regulator with a linear one in series. Is that really needed?

I know the switching ones may have output noise but can't that be solved with a few passive components right after the regulator ?

Comment: To reduce the output of a switching regulator to have no noise would require a very large number of filtering components. The linear regulator replaces a great many of them.

Comment: Why wouldn't a few capacitors do the trick? Too many different frequencies?

Comment: How many you need depends on how little noise you want in the output. At some point there will be too much capacitance and the regulator will blow on startup.

Comment: And a Zener? Not fast enough the absorb the switching through him?

Comment: A zener regulator is inferior in every way to a linear IC regulator.

Comment: True. One last question: since a lot of IC's today (especially MCUs) have internal voltage regulator (e.g. 5v input but 3.3v working voltage internally), then is it really needed to supply the MCU with a very stable voltage? Not considering the ADC reference pin but just the normal supply lines.

Comment: Well, this is an application-specific question, but in general if your supply goes more than 10% out of regulation then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Felipe_Ribas Read the data sheet. Each supply pin should have a max and min voltage. An MCU of mine says 2v to 6v, so I only use voltages in that range to supply it. However, elsewhere, it says 16MHz clock only works at 4.5v and above, and 8MHz clock works down to 3v. So I can't use all of the input voltage range with certain clocks. Read and understand the datasheet of the part you want to power.

Comment: Whether a linear post-regulator is necessary is application dependent; an ADC or DAC with 16 bit (or possibly lower and definitely for higher) resolution? You bet. A digital I/O driver power source? Probably not. You really need to scope the question in terms of a particular application.

Comment: Yea I'm being very broad because I saw somebody else's design and I was questioning about it. Then I was wondering if there was any general rule for this. But then it raises me one more question:  say a datasheet specify that a particular MCU can work with 4v to 6v input. And before this MCU I have a switching power regulator with 5v output. As we know, the regulator output has a lot of noise. However is probably noise around 5v. So if the noise is kept between 4v and 6v, is this still a problem?